# Android MVVM who should read and store bundle

Tags: java, android, mvvm

I have a simple activity with a couple of text and an image, I get the data for this view elements with a bundle when the activity is created.
Now I'm trying to change the architecture to MVVM and I was wondering how and where to store the bundle info?

For what I've been reading the data should be at the "model" level, but I already have the data in the bundle, should I be creating a model and storing the data there or in the ViewModel?

My ViewModel looks like this:

```
public class SimpleInfoViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private Context context;

    public SimpleInfoViewModel(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

}
```

And my view:

```
public class SimpleInfoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SimpleInfoViewModel viewModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getViewBundledInfo();

        initViewModel();
    }

    private void getViewBundledInfo() {
        final Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            title = extras.getString("title");
        }
    }

    private void initViewModel() {
        SimpleInfoViewModel viewModel = new SimpleInfoViewModel(this);
    }
```

Comment: Never instantiate ViewModel like that.Use `ViewModelProviders.of()` factory method for instantiating them

Comment: Do not store Activity references in the viewmodel. ViewModel outlives activities so you´ll end up memory leaking. If by some reason you need to use context from within the view model use getApplication context rather than this, and use AndroidViewModel to make intent clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a class called SimpleInfoViewModelFactory extends ViewModelProviders.Factory.

```
SimpleInfoViewModelFactory(String title) extends ViewModelProviders.Factory {.. copy paste codr from document.. .}
```

The way tou create your ViewModel inside the activity is totally wrong

```
SimpleInfoViewModelFactory vmf = SimpleInfoViewModelFactory(bundle.extras.title)
SimpleInfoViewModel vm = VieeModelProvders.of(this,vmf).get(SimpleInfoViewModel.class)
```

This creates a ViewModel like now but you use it to have initalised values. You can see on the docs. Its very easy